# Homebrew broken - "cannot load such file -- vendor/bundle/bundler/setup (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby, homebrew, bundler

Every time I try to run a `brew` command, it gives the following error:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- vendor/bundle/bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/load_path.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:8:in `require_relative'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:17:in `require_relative'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my Ruby/Bundler, since bundler works completely fine in other cases. What might the problem be?

Comment: Having same issue - few 'answers' I've found haven't made sense to me.

Comment: found a fix yet?

Answer (score 14):

`brew update-reset && brew update` worked for me.

Comment: I did a fresh Mojave install and the first thing I did was install Brew using the http://brew.sh oneliner. I encountered this error even though `brew update` said "Already up-to-date." This resolved that.

Comment: If you're getting a 'LoadError' while trying to run commands in Homebrew, this answer fixes that problem too.